# How do I annotate a ggtree object with bootstrap values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics, phylogeny, ggtree

I have a phylogenetic tree of the class `phylo` with 24 tips and 23 internal nodes. I ran a bootstrap analysis on this tree and the data using `boot.phylo`, which returned a vector of 23 bootstrap values. I created a ggtree object from my original tree and am now trying to add the bootstrap values to the nodes. I am doing something wrong but I don't know what.

Here is what I did:

```
gg.tr <- ggtree(mp.tree)
gg.tr + geom_label2(aes(subset=!isTip, label=bphylo$BP))
```

`bphylo$BP` is the vector of 23 bootstrap values. When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (47): subset, label, x, y
```

I don't understand this error, because I only want to put the bootstrap values on 23 of the possible 47 locations.

When I call the following function, I get a value of 23:

```
length(which(gg.tr$data$isTip==FALSE))
```

If the length of `gg.tr$data$isTip==FALSE` is 23 and I have 23 bootstrap values, why am I getting an error telling me that my label is the wrong length?

Comment: Without having a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2359523) it is difficult to say why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can annotate your tree with `geom_text`. Without seeing your data, it's hard to know what is happening, but here is an example with a reproducible dataset.

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("GuangchuangYu/ggtree")

bs <- data.frame(nodename = c("t30", "t12", "t22", "t26", "t6", "t17", "t4","t7", "t9", "t1", "t8", "t25","t23",
                          "t28", "t10", "t20", "t3",  "t11", "t19", "t29", "t2","t18", "t24",
                          "t27", "t15", "t13", "t14", "t16", "t5","t21"), bootstrap = c(runif(30, 85, 98)), stringsAsFactors = F)
bs$bootstrap <- round(bs$bootstrap, digits = 0)
rownames(bs) <- NULL
nodesupport = c(round(runif(59, 65, 80), digits = 0))

set.seed(0)
tree <- rtree(30)
p <- ggtree(tree)
p <- p %<+% bs + geom_tiplab()
p <- p + geom_text(aes(label = bootstrap), hjust = 1, vjust = -0.4, size = 3) + geom_nodelab(aes(label = nodesupport)) # specify your node label here, looks like BP
p
```

[image]

Comment: This may also be of use. https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/ggtree/inst/doc/treeAnnotation.html

Comment: The link above no longer works. See https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ggtree/inst/doc/ggtree.html